# Foreach through 2 arrays only loops the first element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I create 2 different arrays `$postvalues` and `$filut` from form inputs. I then send the arrays to my database table on button click. The arrays consist of file name and a small introduction.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) 
{
    $filut = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
}
if(isset($_POST['subi'])) 
{
     $data1 = $_POST['answers'];
     foreach($data1) as $postValues) 
     {
         $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO db_image (text, image) VALUES("'.$postValues.'","'.$filut.'")';
         $my->query($sql4);
     }
}
```

The problem here is the output. The foreach loop outputs `$postValues` correctly but only duplicates `$filut` first element.

Example of the false output:

```
 this is picture1  picture1.png
 this is picture2  picture1.png  //Supposed to say 2nd element of $filut: "picture2.png"
```

Foreach goes through the first array properly but only duplicates the `$filut` array. I've tried searching for answer and I've tried combining the arrays but without any success.

How do I loop through both arrays properly and insert them to database?

Comment: Have you declared $filut ad an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you were trying to used nested loops, but you in fact had one loop at the beginning which closed out and then you loop through the rest. You need to move your closing curly brace marked below:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  $filut = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
 } <<<<<<<<<=========== This curly brace closes the "for loop"
if(isset($_POST['subi'])) {
 $data1 = $_POST['answers'];
 foreach($data1) as $postValues) {
 $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO db_image (text, image) VALUES("'.$postValues.'","'.$filut.'")';
 $my->query($sql4);
 }
} 
??? <<<<<======== For a nested loop you should close it here
```

or perhaps you were trying to assign `$filut` as an array in which case the starting `for...` loop needs to look like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  $filut[] = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
 }
```

(Note the addition of `[]` after `$filut`.)

However, if this is what you were intending (to make $filut into an array) then you need to do something different down below in order to access just one element of the array. This is where a nested `foreach` would solve the problem - maybe this is how you intended to finish it off:

```
if(isset($_POST['subi'])) {
    $data1 = $_POST['answers'];
    foreach($data1 as $postValues) {
        foreach ($filut as $f) {
            $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO db_image (text, image)
                     VALUES("'.$postValues.'","'.$f.'")';
            $my->query($sql4);
        }
    }
}
```

This will insert a row for every value in $filut for every value in $_POST['answers']. Is that what you wanted? Or are $filut and $_POST['answers'] in parallel and you want a 1-1 correlation on the insert?

Finally I'm going to suggest that you use prepare and bind since you are getting your data from the user. This example copied/modified from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$query = "INSERT INTO db_image (text, image) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = $my->prepare($query);

#### NOTE THE USE OF YOUR VARIABLES HERE IN THE BIND - the "ss" means they are strings
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $postValues, $f);

#### HERE IS WHERE YOUR CODE IS GETTING INSERTED
foreach($data1 as $postValues) {
    foreach ($filut as $f) {
        /* Execute the statement */
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$my->close();
?>
```

I can't guarantee that I got all the variables changed to match your code, but hopefully it's close enough to give you an idea. This solution (1) protects you from SQL Injection (which is a serious flaw in your code otherwise) and (2) will be much faster by means of the prepare/execute cycle.

*Do note the careful indentation in my examples where everything lines up perfectly with 3 or more spaces per indent - I can't tell you how many times I have seen sloppy (or too little) indentation make people miss problems which would be otherwise obvious.*

Comment: I got it to work finally. All of the answers helped more or less but I used this one mostly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your database query is insecure in that it is sending raw POST data directly to the database. Validate your input, and use prepared statements instead. 
Your error is here:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
    $filut = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
}
```

$filut is getting reassigned to the last element of $_FILES. Hence only holding one value. Is $filut supposed to be an array instead? 

Try this instead:

```php
$filut = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) 
{
    $filut[$i] = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
}

$i = 0; //Reset
if(isset($_POST['subi'])) 
{
    $data1 = $_POST['answers'];
    foreach($data1 as $postValues) 
    {
        $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO db_image (text, image) VALUES("'.$postValues.'","'.$filut[$i].'")';
        $my->query($sql4);
        $i++ //Increment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of files uploaded is equal to the length of the $data array i'd try this:

```
$data1 = $_POST['answers'];
for($i=0; $i<length($data); $i++){
    $filut = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
    if(isset($_POST['subi'])) {
        $postValue = $data[$i];
        $sql4 = 'INSERT INTO db_image (text, image) VALUES("'.$postValues.'","'.$filut.'")';
        $my->query($sql4);
    }
}
```